# @MEDIA CSS Query Breaks Styling

Tags: html, css, wordpress, media-queries

So for some reasons when I add the @ media query to my wordpress stylesheet, it breaks the styling of the first container. I have the proper brackets so I'm kind of confused as to why my code editor greys out the first container, in this case #navmenu.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1001px) and (max-width: 1499px) {
#navmenu {
    margin-top: 50px;
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    margin-left:29%;
   }
}
```

The same thing occurs, when I try to @media query wrap the original stylesheet to only load when the screen size is >1500px. The site's #wrapper breaks and all styling after that is broken, as if my brackets are not properly placed.

Comment: Sounds like a case of misplaced control character. Run your CSS through a validator and see if anything comes up.

Comment: what browser are you using ? try taking the only out and see if it helpps.

Comment: Billy I've tried to use with and without the only, it has zero effect on the code ignoring the first CSS container. I've tried looking at it in both the latest versions of Firefox & Chrome, no difference in either. Bolt I'll try the validator now and report back.

Comment: So I ran the validator and my code was fine, so I just implemented the code in my live site and it worked fine. So it seems the issue has more to do with Jedit not understanding the @media query then an issue with how the actual web browsers are rendering the code. What a headache! Thanks for the help everyone! :)